# Tablet PC Autocomplete

Tags: c#, vb.net, autocomplete, windows-vista, tablet

I have been trying to implement the autocomplete functionality mentioned 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695043%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The problem is I am developing on a windows xp machine and I cant seem to find the right dlls used to develop this feature.

Using vista for development is not an option, but the production environment is on a Vista Tablet PC. I have downloaded and installed the Tablet PC SDK version 1.7 to no avail (still cant find the libraries).

The implementation seems to use COM libraries. The examples are all written in C++ and I am developing in .NET.

Has anyone ever successfully implemented this feature?
If so, how did you go about doing it?

Any help will be appreciated

Here is an image showing what I am trying to achieve

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms695043.ba59a513-e538-4092-89a6-6d691424dc3d%28en-us,VS.85%29.jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms695043.ba59a513-e538-4092-89a6-6d691424dc3d%28en-us,VS.85%29.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to call the DLLs directly. As long as your solution is based on .NET Framework 3.0 or above you just need to enable AutoComplete mode on the specific textbox. Deploying your solution to Vista should enable the functionality.

However, one caveat is that the autocomplete integration is for Vista and above only. You will therefore be unable to debug this aspect of your project on an XP machine - you'll have to remotely debug on your Vista Tablet PC. The Tablet PC SDK does not include down-level compatibility for this option on XP as it's baked into the Vista OS.

I hope this helps.